# llamar varias pantallas en otra pantalla Angular

Tags: html, angular, angular-router

Estoy trabajando con Angular 8.1

Estoy intentando hacer una pantalla que contiene secciones de otras pantallas ya programadas, por lo que quiero llamar esas pantallas ya programadas en sus respectivas secciones en la nueva pantalla (mandándoles un parámetro para que se comporten de cierta forma).

Todas las secciones deben ser visibles al mismo tiempo.
¿Es eso posible?

Aqui les dejo una imagen que pretende aclarar la consulta.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intentado usar `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` pero no se si este mal, pero comprendo que de esa forma solo puedo llamar una de mis pantallas requeridas en la pantalla nueva

Comment: Deberías agregar lo que has intentado amigo, checa [ask]

Comment: Puedes tener varios `<router-oulet name='pantallaX'><...`. Checa  [documentacion](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterOutlet)

Comment: En caso de que tus pantallas sean componentes independientes puedes llamar a las distintas pantallas desde una única vista. En esta pagina te explican bastante bien la comunicación entre componentes con angular. https://medium.com/@javifont/3-formas-de-comunicarse-entre-componentes-angular-b349ada25797